# Clear the console after repeating a function by threading module

Tags: python

I want to repeat function using the `threading` module. For example:

```
def func():
  threading.Timer(30, func).start()
  print ('x')
```

After it runs a couple of times, it prints the function in a row without clearing the console. What I want, though, is that it print `x`, wait until the next execution, clear the console and then print `x` again. I am using `Sublime Text Version 3`.

Comment: what u have tried, and what is expected output

Comment: I don't think the editor has anything to do with with the implementation, but whatever. Better give an answer with the full answer rather than an unclear one ;)

Comment: @Roushan I just mentioned the desired outcome at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your `print` statement with

```
print('x', end='\r')
```

This is the way to go if you want to clear the previous output at each iteration. However, in your example, it will seem like you're only printing `'x'` once since your output is always the same.

To make it more visual, try printing a different value every time.